# How to insert the elements of array into the positional parameters of a command in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I need to list all the files that have specific extensions which I can only know at runtime,for example in a particular file. Or the extensions are stored in a variable.

And I want to use the `fd` command to list them. The command to list all files with multiple extension is like `fd -e java -e c ...`.

I tried 2 ways to manage it, but both of them seem ugly.

```
!/bin/zsh
str="c java"
extensions=(${=str})
arguments=(" -e "${^extensions})
# Why `arguments=" -e "${^extensions};echo $arguments` output  -e c java
fd ${=arguments}
```

```
!/bin/zsh
str="c java"
extensions=(${=str})
option=(" -e ")
arguments=${option:^^extensions}
fd ${=arguments}
```

I hope there is a one-line code like `fd ${=${(" -e "):^^(${=str})}}`.

And I have one additional question:
In the first code block, why `arguments=" -e "${^extensions};echo $arguments` output"  -e c java\n" while `arguments=(" -e "${^extensions}); echo $arguments` output " -e c  -e java\n"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split `str`, then prepend `-e` to each array element, and split again.

```
% str="c java"
% print -lr -- ${=${${=str}/#/-e }}
-e
c
-e
java
```

It's uglier and more fragile than it needs to be because the first step is to split a string into a list. If you had the list in an array, you could just prepend and then split:

```
% a=(c java)
% print -lr -- ${=${a/#/-e }}
-e
c
-e
java
```

However, while splitting on `IFS` is short, it isn't right because it breaks on inputs containing spaces (or more generally on `$IFS` characters).

```
% a=(c java "with spaces")
% print -lr -- ${=${a/#/-e }}
-e
c
-e
java
-e
with
spaces
```

I don't think there's a correct one-liner with parameter expansion. There is an ugly one with the `P` glob qualifier, which you can leverage by globbing one thing and substituting a different array.

```
% a=(c java "with spaces")
% print -lr -- .(P\''-e'\'e\''reply=($a)'\')
-e
c
-e
java
-e
with spaces
```

---

> ```
> str="c java"
> extensions=(${=str})
> # Why `arguments=" -e "${^extensions};echo $arguments` output  -e c java
> ```

Because you're creating a string. In a string context, the `^` flag has no effect. Its effect is to create separate array elements, but there's no way to do that when the context doesn't allow an array.